# What do I need to run a node.js script on my server?

Tags: apache, node.js, server-side, socket.io

I have a standard Apache server. Do I need anything special to run a node.js script (http://socket.io/) on the serverside?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Node.js provides its own HTTP server, thus making Apache unnecessary.

If you wish to run Apache and Node.js on the same server, either set node to listen to port 80 and [forward unhandled requests](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to Apache, or [vice versa](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2010/12/how-to-run-apache-and-nodejs.php)

In both instances, Node/Apache will listen to the publicly open port 80, and forward to Apache/Node listening on some non-public port.

Comment: Thank you very much for that information.  A question, please.  It seems to me that it makes more sense from a performance perspective to use Node/Apache instead of Apache/Node.  (assuming that 50% of requests go to Node.js, and 50% to Apache.)  Is that true?

Comment: In my opinion, yes, that is true. Node likely has a much shorter 'path' than Apache for offloading requests as early as possible. Always worth some performance testing, though.

Answer (score 1):

You will need shell access to start the node.js server. So it most likely won't work on shared hosting.

Comment: I have a virtual private server with shell access.

Comment: Then you can simply install node.js. How you do it depends on your distribution (unless you want to compile from source) and if you have questions about it, better ask them on [serverfault.com](http://www.serverfault.com)